# Get rid of button, and have it's effects just be automatic

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I've made my html auto refresh every 60 seconds, but it needs the button to be pressed again, would rather just ditch the button and have it's effects just automatically happen when the html is run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
    <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>
            <br />
            <div align="center">
                <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="employee_table">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#load_data').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "employee.csv",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
                    for (var count = 0; count < employee_data.length; count++) {
                        var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
                        table_data += '<tr>';
                        for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
                            if (count === 0) {
                                table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
                            }
                            else {
                                table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                        table_data += '</tr>';
                    }
                    table_data += '</table>';
                    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

It won't let me submit without adding more, not sure what else to add, the contents of the csv file are going to routinely change, so that's why the website will need to auto-refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "employee.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
                for (var count = 0; count < employee_data.length; count++) {
                    var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
                    table_data += '<tr>';
                    for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
                        if (count === 0) {
                            table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
                        }
                        else {
                            table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
                        }
                    }
                    table_data += '</tr>';
                }
                table_data += '</table>';
                $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
            }
        });
    });
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **setInterval** in your javascript file. Make sure that the ajax call is inside a function so you don't have to rewrite again the code.

For example

```
function autoload(){
  //your ajax call here..}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
setInterval(autoload,3000) //convert 60 seconds to milliseconds
```